# Over-Indexed a MySQL table. How can I remediate?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 3 million rows and 6 columns. The problem is that my mysqld server wouldn't generate the output for any query and it would simply time out.

I then read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446142/157880) that over-indexing could involve too much of swapping data from memory to disk and can cause the server to slow down.

So I ran a query `ALTER TABLE <Tbl_name> DROP INDEX <Index_name>;`. This query has been running for 10 hours and has not completed yet.

1. Is this expected to run for so long?
2. Is there a better way to Dropping/Altering my indices?

**edit - Added SHOW CREATE TABLE output**

```
| Sample | CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FiMD5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `NoMD5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `SeMD5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `SeesMD5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `ImMD5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Ovlay` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FiMD5_3` (`FiMD5`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_2` (`ID`),
  KEY `pIndex` (`FiMD5`),
  KEY `FiMD5_` (`FiMD5`,`NoMD5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3073630 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Show us what `SHOW CREATE <Tbl_name>` outputs and what `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` outputs

Comment: Please post your table definition. Three million rows doesn't sound like it should be such a huge problem. My guess is that after 10 hours, it's safe to conclude that something's broken (unless mysqld is running on an Atari or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps do the following would be faster:

1. `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` first
2. Use `TRUNCATE TABLE` to delete everything
3. Modify the table
4. Use `LOAD` to restore the data

If step 2 takes too long, perhaps dropping the table and recreate it.

Comment: I did step 1 and 2. Now the Table contains 0 rows. But I can't find the outfile. I just specified the name 'db_bkup.txt' and I am in Windows. *I sincerely hope all my data hasn't vanished*

Comment: You just saved from serious problems. Thanks for the neat workaround.