# Are foreign keys that are part of a composite key automatically indexed in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, foreign-keys, primary-key

For instance, if I have a students table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id NUMBER(8),
    student_name VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_student PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);
```

And a subject table:

```
CREATE TABLE subject (
    subject_id NUMBER(8),
    subject_name VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_subject PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
);
```

And then I create a third table of student's favorites subjects:

```
CREATE TABLE fav_sub (
    student_id NUMBER(8),
    subject_it NUMBER(8),
    CONSTRAINT pk_fav_sub PRIMARY KEY (student_id, subject_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_1_fav_sub FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(student_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_2_fav_sub FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(subject_id)
);
```

Do I then need to manually create indexes for the foreign keys in the fav_sub table such as:

```
CREATE INDEX in_1_fav_sub ON fav_sub(student_id);
CREATE INDEX in_2_fav_sub ON fav_sub(subject_id);
```

Or are the indexes for the foreign keys automatically created by the database, since they're part of the composite key?

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm not asking if an index for a foreign key is automatically created, I'm asking if an index for a foreign key is created WHEN it's part of a composite key, since Oracle automatically indexes primary keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to create indexes on foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127206/do-i-need-to-create-indexes-on-foreign-keys)

Comment: Oracle only creates indexes automatically when absolutely required (i.e. to support a unique constraint). Otherwise, it never creates an index for you unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Also, it has nothing to do with whether it's a composite or simple key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of the primary key indexes the combination of `[student_id, subject_id]`. Adding foreign key constraints to each individual column does not create an index on them, and if you want it (which is probably a good idea), you'd have to manually create it.