# Lots of slow queries even "SELECT ... WHERE id=..." and "SET TIMESTAMP" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, webserver, innodb, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm using PHP and MySQL/InnoDB.

I have a main `News` table with around **500K** rows.
Three other tables are `Source`(max 500 rows), `Category`(12 rows) and `Tag`(average 2 tags for each record in `News`) which I frequently use in join with `News`. Most of my SELECT queries have three joins (between `News`, `Source` and `Category`).

Another table is `OldNews` which is used to store news that are not important for most of queries. They exist only for getting selected by id in permalinks. This table has about **3M** records.

Sometimes strange queries get into the slow_query_log:

```
# Query_time: 30.839378  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1481914895;
# administrator command: Prepare;
```

(**Edit**: I don't know whether Prepare command belongs to this query or not. I just edited so it might help).

Another query:

```
# Query_time: 22.986259  Lock_time: 0.000026 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1481915053;
SELECT id FROM News WHERE id=1800004;
```

where id is the primary key, or

```
# Query_time: 18.006325  Lock_time: 0.000016 Rows_sent: 20  Rows_examined: 60
SET timestamp=1481915053;
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
News.id, News.title,
Source.name AS source_name, Category.name AS category_name
FROM News
INNER JOIN Source ON News.source=Source.id
INNER JOIN Category ON News.category=Category.id
WHERE News.category=11
ORDER BY News.last_suggestion_time DESC limit 20;
```

where (category, last_suggestion_time) is a compound index in `News` table.

So the question is:
What's making this mess? Is it that `SET TIMESTAMP`?

Some server configs:

```
RAM: 4G
CPU: Dual Core 2000
MySQL: 5.5.31
Apache: 2.2.26
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
long_query_time = 5
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/slow_query_log.log

// these settings are suggested by mysqltuner, but there was no change in performance
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
max_connections = 160
query_cache_type = 0
thread_cache_size = 4
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

Comment: Have you indexed your three tables?

Comment: @leeyuiwah Yes. id is the primary key for all of them.

Comment: How about News.source and News.category?

Comment: @leeyuiwah No, they're not. But they are indexed as a part of compound index like the one I mentioned for News.category.

Comment: Then you may want to try index the two columns and see if that helps.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4127238/1168041

Comment: @leeyuiwah Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: I remembered that source and category are the first part of some compound indices. For example (source, number_of_views), (category, number_of_views), ... are indices. What kind of index do you mean?