# An example of indexing Oracle foreign keys

Tags: oracle

How do I index a foreign key(column cnt004_id) for a table?

There is a table ChildTable:

```
CREATE TABLE ChildTable (
    id NUMBER GENERATED as IDENTITY,
    cnt004_id int not null,
    tariff_dist NUMBER not null,
    foreign key (cnt004_id) references ParentTable(id)
);
```

I don't have any foreign key indexes created.

Comment: Why do you expect that a `FOREIGN KEY` column needs an index? The column it references on the parent table must have either a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on it which will be backed by a `UNIQUE` index but there is no requirement for the referencing column on the child table to have an index.

Comment: In parent table - PRIMARY KEY

Comment: It's important to index the child column or deletes on the parent table will be terribly slow, requiring a full table scan of the child for every row deleted as it does its internal check on child rows to ensure it isn't about to orphan them. In a multi-user situation this will likely cause locking issues for the app for the duration.

Comment: Paul W is correct. MT0 is apparently not aware of the issue at hand. Refer to " Foreign Keys, Indexes and Locking (Doc ID 1945574.1)" Refer also to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127206/do-i-need-to-create-indexes-on-foreign-keys-on-oracle

Answer (score 1):

With a `create index` command.

Sample parent table:

```
SQL> create table parenttable
  2    (id int primary key);

Table created.
```

Your child table (this code isn't changed in any way):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ChildTable (
  2      id NUMBER GENERATED as IDENTITY,
  3      cnt004_id int not null,
  4      tariff_dist NUMBER not null,
  5      foreign key (cnt004_id) references ParentTable(id)
  6  );

Table created.
```

Create index:

```
SQL> create index i1_ct_cnt004 on childtable (cnt004_id);

Index created.

SQL>
```

---

Because, unlike primary key constraints - for which Oracle automatically creates unique index that supports it (if it doesn't exist):

```
SQL> select index_name, uniqueness, constraint_index
  2  from user_indexes where table_name = 'PARENTTABLE';

INDEX_NAME                     UNIQUENES CON
------------------------------ --------- ---
SYS_C0010080                   UNIQUE    YES

SQL>
```

Oracle doesn't do the same for foreign key constraints, so - you have to do it yourself (if you want to have that column indexed).